# problema de conjuntos

Tags: matemáticas, conjuntos

PASCO entrevistó la semana pasada a 160 personas para conocer su opinión sobre sus productos Kumis y Yogurt. Tabulados los datos obtenidos se concluyo que: 120 consumen por lo menos uno de los dos productos, 60 consumen Kumis, 60 consumen Yogurt. La fabrica esta interesada en saber lo siguiente:

1. a. El numero de personas que consumen ambos productos.
2. b. El numero de personas que consumen solamente Kumis.
3. c. El numero de personas que consumen solamente Yogurt.
4. d. El numero de personasque no consumen ninguno de los dos.
5. e. El numero de personas que consumen exactamente uno de los dos.

Comment: la pregunta no versa sobre programación y por tanto es seguro termine cerrada

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es un problema de programación.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De acuerdo con que éste no es el canal adecuado para preguntar, porque la pregunta es de matemáticas y no tiene nada de programación.

Dicho esto, la solución es trivial si asumimos que los datos son ciertos y están bien tabulados.
Si hay 120 que consumen al menos uno de los productos (podría ser uno o dos), los que no consumen ninguno son (total - 120) = 160 - 120 = 40.
Por otro lado, si 60 consumen Kumis y 60 consumen Yogurt, tienes que sumar ambos para llegar a 120, de lo que se deduce que ninguno consume los dos juntos. De lo contrario, la suma tendría que ser mayor a 120.